# iOS - Fetch Facebook friends using Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get the list of my friends from Facebook using Graph API in my iOS app. I am getting the friends list. But the concern is i would like to get them in batches like their name starting from A to F and then from F to M and so on. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Below is the code snippet that i use to get my friends list.

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:@{@"fields":@"id, name,first_name,last_name,link,username,gender,locale,picture,birthday,locations,checkins"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                          NSDictionary* result,
                                                          NSError *error) {
                NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
                NSArray *unsortedFriends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
}
)];
```